# Is it possible to use a wildcard in mongodb find()?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, find

`db.collection.find( { Destination : "wildcard?" } )`: wildcard would be something that would return everything in the `Destination` column of the collection.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find the unique values of the `Destination` field?

Comment: You can specify an empty filter for "all" selection. Or, use a "regex" query, for a pattern match. Or, if you have a list of values to select from, use the `$in` operator.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get all of the values in the destination column of spreadsheet which has been imported into mongodb.

Comment: If you want to get all of the values in the destination you can do: `db.collection.distinct('destination')`. Also, you can get the total of each value with  aggregate with `$group` as follows: `db.collection.aggregate([{ $group: {_id: '$Destination', total: {$sum: 1}}}])`.